# Bit Fields in Java

Tags: java, endianness, bit-fields

What is the best way to extract bit fields in Java prior to 1.7? I know I can use bitwise operations, but isn't it better methods?

I need to extract the portion of bit array with endianness control as integer values.

Comment: Why does endianness affect anything?

Comment: @Suzan Cioc: Java handles the endianness when extracting bit fields.

Comment: Normally the endianess is in reading/writing the data from a Stream or Channel. Extracting the bits is a seperate step. bitwise operations are the simplest way to operate on bits (thus the name)

Comment: @Oli because. If I know that field is from bits number 10 and 11, I can't extract them without knowing endianness.

Comment: @Peter how to set endianness when reading?

Comment: I would use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder)` and then get the 10th and 11th bit.

Comment: @Peter, how to get bits from `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: You get an `int` value using `getInt()` You have to get the value first, then extract the bits.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Bit #10 is always `(x & (1 << 10))`.  The only place endianness matters is if `x` has come from some external interface (like a network packet or something).  But if that's the case, you should deal with the endianness when you read the data in, rather than every time you need to extract information from it.